# How to add kernel module parameters?

Tags: 11.04, kernel-modules, modules

How to add a kernel module parameter in Ubuntu 11.04?

Can I use the `/etc/module` file? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you mean parameters like `i915.modeset=1`?

Comment: I mean 'options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1' in a file under /etc/modprobe.d/ or 'thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1' in /etc/modules ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`/etc/modules` seems to be loaded by `/etc/init/module-init-tools.conf`. The first argument is the module name, other arguments are the parameters. Adding the following to `/etc/modules` seems fine:

```
thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1
```

To load this module and set these parameters in the very early stage of boot, add the previous line to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` file. After a change in that file, you need to regenerate the ramdisk:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

As a possible alternative, you can try to add the options to the kernel line (I haven't tested it myself, but it seems to work for settings like `i915.modeset=1`. Edit `/etc/default/grub` and find the line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`. Replace it by something like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash thinkpad_acpi.fan_control=1"
```

To get a list of options for a kernel module:

```
modinfo -p thinkpad_acpi
```

This did not work for `i915`, for that I had to run:

```
modinfo i915 | grep ^parm
```

To get the current value of a module parameter, run:

```
sudo cat /sys/module/MODULE/parameters/PARAM
```

For the `fan_control` parameter of the `thinkpad_acpi` module, you have to run:

```
sudo cat /sys/module/thinkpad_acpi/parameters/fan_control
```

If this function returns an error, check if the module was loaded and whether the option exist or not.

Comment: How to know a parameter of module have took effect ? thanks

Comment: @waterloo2005: You can use `/sys` for that. See the revised answer.

Comment: I find I do not add parameter in /etc/modules. I only need to add them in /etc/modprobe.d/ .
Thanks

Comment: The distinction between `/etc/modules` and `/etc/modprobe.d`: the first applies to modules loaded in the early stage of boot (right after Plymouth starts), the latter is loaded later (by initscripts)

Comment: Where can I find official instructions about it ? thanks

Comment: I found it out by analysing the source code, you can confirm that modules in modprobe.d is loaded as initscript in `/etc/init/module-init-tools.conf` and `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/functions` line 339 (`load_modules`, this script is called from `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/init` which is copied into a initrd). Manual pages: `man mkinitramfs`, `man modules`

Comment: 'sudo cat /sys/module/thinkpad_acpi/parameters/fan_control' gives me 'N' .  How to open this function ?

Comment: What do you mean by "open"? Make it 1?

Comment: Which function? Fan control? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes , I mean if I need to add 'echo Y > /sys/module/thinkpad_acpi/parameters/fan_control' in my rc.local to make it work.

Comment: Have you added `thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1` to `/etc/modules` and executed `suo update-initramfs -u` afterwards?

Comment: Thanks, A few days ago I install ubuntu11.10 . And forgot to add the line to /etc/modules. Now cat /sys/module/thinkpad_acpi/parameters/fan_control gives Y.

Answer (score 18):

**Setting module options using files in /etc/modprobe.d/**

Files in /etc/modprobe.d/ directory can be used to pass module settings to udev, which will use modprobe to manage the loading of the modules during system boot. Configuration files in this directory can have any name, given that they end with the .conf extension. The syntax is:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/myfilename.conf
---------------------------------------------------------
options modname parametername=parametervalue
```

For example:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf
---------------------------------------------------------
# On ThinkPads, this lets the 'thinkfan' daemon control fan speed
options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1
```

Source:[Kernel modules - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_modules)

---

As far as I know, you can use the mentioned method for modules that are automatically loaded at boot time (to avoid unloading and reloading modules with special parameters, as this might be the case for driver modules), and the `/etc/modules` file for modules that are not automatically loaded at boot time.

Answer (score 10):

With Ubuntu 16.04 one can no longer include kernel module parameters in `/etc/modules`. An error is generated in the boot log saying it can't find "my_kernel_mod myparam=x".

Instead one needs to put only the kernel module name in `/etc/modules` and put the options in `/etc/modprobe.d/myfilename.conf` (as suggested [above](https://askubuntu.com/a/496842/233795)).