# Mount single partition from image of entire disk (device)

Tags: mount, backup, disk, dd, disk-image

I made an image of my entire disk with

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/external_media/sda.img
```

Now the problem is I'd like to mount an ext4 filesystem that was on that disk but

```
mount -t ext4 -o loop /media/external_media/sda.img /media/sda_image
```

obviously gives a superblock error since the image contains the whole disk (MBR, other partitions) not just the partition I need. So I guess I should find a way to make the disk image show up in the `/dev/` folder...

Does anyone know how to do that?

PS: I can always `dd` back the image to the original disk, but that would be very inconvenient (I updated the OS and I'd like to keep it as it is)

Comment: You can consider this: https://technewskb.com/mount-dd-image-linux-using-terminal-commands/ or this: https://lettoknow.com/techniques-mount-dd-image-file/

Answer (score 202, accepted):

**Get the partition layout of the image**

```
$ sudo fdisk -lu sda.img
...
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
...
  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
sda.img1   *          56     6400000     3199972+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

**Calculate the offset from the start of the image to the partition start**

*Sector size* * *Start* = (in the case) 512 * 56 = **28672**

**Mount it on /dev/loop0 using the offset**

```
sudo losetup -o 28672 /dev/loop0 sda.img
```

Now the partition resides on */dev/loop0*. You can *fsck* it, mount it etc

```
sudo fsck -fv /dev/loop0
sudo mount /dev/loop0 /mnt
```

**Unmount**

```
sudo umount /mnt
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm! You made my day (and saved an innocent Ocelot from being brutally deleted ;P)

Comment: At least on bash, the shell can even do the math for you: `sudo losetup -o $((56*512)) /dev/loop0 sda.img`

Comment: This is not just helpful, this is absolutely awesome.

Comment: What if there's a .img1 and .img2?
"win8.raw1   *        2048      718847      358400    7" and "win8.raw2          718848    52426751    25853952    7"

Comment: Why does this work even though we do not specify FS when mounting?

Comment: Even simpler: `mount -o loop,offset=$((56 * 512)) sda.img /mnt`. Source: http://madduck.net/blog/2006.10.20:loop-mounting-partitions-from-a-disk-image/

Comment: `*Sector size* * *Start*` is better as `512 * 56` (not `56 * 512`). edited.

Comment: @JernejJerin the mount command (as setup on Ubuntu and other distros) is able to auto-detect many filesystem types, so you often don't need to specify the filesystem.

Comment: I would recommend specifying mounting point when mounting

Comment: Perfect :) worked like charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 154):

**Update for Ubuntu 16.04:** With the new `losetup` this is now easier:

```
sudo losetup -Pf disk_image.raw
```

See the rest of the answer for older versions of Ubuntu.

---

An easy solution is using [kpartx](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/kpartx): it will figure out the partition layout and map each to a block devices. After that all you have to do is mount the one you want.

Open Terminal, locate the disk image, and enter this command:

```
$ sudo kpartx -av disk_image.raw 
add map loop0p1 (252:2): 0 3082240 linear /dev/loop0 2048
add map loop0p2 (252:3): 0 17887232 linear /dev/loop0 3084288
```

This created `loop0p1` and `loop0p2` under `/dev/mapper`. From the output you can see the sizes of the partitions which helps you identify them. You can mount the one you want with:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p2 /mnt
```

Alternatively, the block device is detected by Nautilus and you can mount it from the side bar:

[image]

When you are done, unmount what you mounted and remove the device mapping:

```
$ sudo umount /mnt
$ sudo kpartx -d disk_image.raw
```

Comment: Excellent answer, quick and easy, avoiding the multiplication step is nice

Comment: `sudo apt-get install kpartx` - to get access to kpartx. The `kpartx` link in the beginning of the post is a 'trap' in my opinion. Links that imply installing software is a no-no.

Comment: @Hannu, links that integrate with Software Center are a [common practice on askubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/548/how-to-post-links-that-integrate-with-the-software-center), though in this particular case the typical icon could be added and the URL should be updated.

Comment: `losetup -Pf` had been previously mentioned by http://askubuntu.com/a/496576/52975 I recommend that you at least link to that answer.

Comment: FYI, the `losetup -Pf ..` command will create devices like `/dev/loopXpY` that you still need to mount. You can find the `X` from looking at the output of the `losetup` command. The `Y` is the partition number.

Comment: As @Gunchars says, `sudo losetup -Pf disk_image.raw` only creates the loopback device but *does not mount it*! You still have to mount it! Either do that manually with `mount` or (my preference) just use the Disks GUI utility to choose the newly-created loop device and graphically mount it by clicking the play button (triangle pointing to the right).

Comment: Also add `--show` to the `losetup` command, as @Ludovic Ronsin says here (https://askubuntu.com/a/496576/327339), so you can see which loop device number is being created.

Comment: and  in the end `losetup -D` to detach all loop devices.

Answer (score 42):

**Edit** : works with ***util-linux >=2.21***. At the time of writing ubuntu ships with version *2.20* only

From *man losetup* :

```
       -P, --partscan
          force kernel to scan partition table on newly created loop device
```

So just run

```
$ sudo losetup -f --show -P /path/to/image.img
```

to create device nodes for every partition of your disk image on the first unused loop device and print it to stdout.
If using `/dev/loop0` device it will create at least `/dev/loop0p1` that you will be able to mount as usual.

Comment: Where do I find this version of `losetup` ?  The one I have in Ubuntu 14.04 has a manpage from July 2003 (util-linux) and no ` -P ` option (or anything else) for scanning partitions.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I've been using this option on Arch Linux which comes with a more recent version of util-linux package.
It seems that Ubuntu is sadly stuck on version 2.20.1 which has been released on january 2012 !
The `--partscan` option has been introduced in [util-linux 2.21](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.21/v2.21-ReleaseNotes)

Comment: Well, `gnome-disks` has an option to mount a disk image and it's partitions. (<- that is for installing and bash/Terminal use, `Disks`in the dash finds it too).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer ...

Comment: @matthid Is it even _possible_ to change an accepted answer? This is good (and the kpartx answer is actually dependent on this version of `losetup`), but it's almost three years newer than the accepted answer—which was the way to do it at the time.

Comment: @Auspex The OP can (and should!) change the accepted answer. This is the modern way to get partitions. For the last 4 years, that is.

Comment: @Navin Actually, since writing that I'd come across an answer that _was_ changed, so I know that it can be done, now. Yeah, `losetup` may have been around long enough, but even this answer agrees that it wasn't an option on a stock Ubuntu setup at the time.

Answer (score 13):

Try `gnome-disk-image-mounter`:

```
gnome-disk-image-mounter sda.img
```

No `sudo` required. It will be mounted at `/media/your_user_name/partition_name`, just like USB drives.

Comment: Was working well on 16.04. I just installed a fresh 18.04 and the tools asks for sudo password in order access the /dev/loopXX virtual device :(

Answer (score 9):

**`losetup -P` automation**

`losetup -P` is the best method starting in Ubuntu 16.04 as mentioned at https://askubuntu.com/a/496576/52975 , here are functions to automate if further. Usage:

```
$ los my.img
/dev/loop0
/mnt/loop0p1
/mnt/loop0p2

$ ls /mnt/loop0p1
/whatever
/files
/youhave
/there

$ sudo losetup -l
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE                                                                                      DIO
/dev/loop1         0      0         0  0 /full/path/to/my.img

$ # Cleanup.
$ losd 0
$ ls /mnt/loop0p1
$ ls /dev | grep loop0
loop0
```

Source:

```
los() (
  img="$1"
  dev="$(sudo losetup --show -f -P "$img")"
  echo "$dev"
  for part in "$dev"?*; do
    if [ "$part" = "${dev}p*" ]; then
      part="${dev}"
    fi
    dst="/mnt/$(basename "$part")"
    echo "$dst"
    sudo mkdir -p "$dst"
    sudo mount "$part" "$dst"
  done
)
losd() (
  dev="/dev/loop$1"
  for part in "$dev"?*; do
    if [ "$part" = "${dev}p*" ]; then
      part="${dev}"
    fi
    dst="/mnt/$(basename "$part")"
    sudo umount "$dst"
  done
  sudo losetup -d "$dev"
)
```

**loop module max_part config**

This is a decent method before 16.04.

`loop` is a kernel module, built into the kernel in Ubuntu 14.04.

If you configure it right, Linux automatically splits up the devices for you.

```
cat /sys/module/loop/parameters/max_part
```

says how many partitions `loop` devices can generate.

It is `0` by default on Ubuntu 14.04 which is why no auto-splitting happens.

To change it, we can either add:

```
options loop max_part=31
```

to a file in `/etc/modprobe`, or:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="loop.max_part=31"
```

to `/etc/default/grub` and then `sudo update-grub`.

How to set a module parameter is also covered at: [How to add kernel module parameters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51226/how-to-add-kernel-module-parameters)

After a reboot, when you do:

```
sudo losetup -f --show my.img
```

it mounts the image to a `/dev/loopX` device, and automatically mounts the partitions to `/dev/loopXpY` devices.

So this is the most convenient method if you are willing to reboot.

**See also**

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/reading-a-filesystem-from-a-whole-disk-image
- https://superuser.com/questions/117136/how-can-i-mount-a-partition-from-dd-created-image-of-a-block-device-e-g-hdd-u
- [Mount single partition from image of entire disk (device)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419489/loopback-mounting-individual-partitions-from-within-a-file-that-contains-a-parti

Answer (score 8):

Use losetup to attach the whole disk image.

```
# sudo losetup /dev/loop2 sda.img
```

Then use mdadm to create an md device and block devices will be created for all of the partitions.

```
# sudo mdadm --build --level=0 --force --raid-devices=1 /dev/md2 /dev/loop2
mdadm: array /dev/md2 built and started.
```

Now you should see the partition devices.

```
nile-172-b0fef38-76:/mnt/sdb1 # ls -l /dev/md2*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   9, 2 Oct 10 12:37 /dev/md2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 0 Oct 10 12:37 /dev/md2p1
```

Comment: That's a funny trick :)

Comment: the easiest way to do it thank

Comment: Tip: To remove them after using: `mdadm --stop /dev/md2` + `mdadm --remove /dev/md2`

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way, in my opinion, is using `mount -o loop,offset=...` as mentioned [in this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1421075/1286717). The idea is as follows:

```
fdisk -l $IMAGE
# calculate the offset in bytes
mount -o loop,offset=$OFFSET $IMAGE $MOUNTPOINT
```

The method is best because it doesn't require deleting the loop device after you umount the mounted partition.

To further simplify the task (which is needed if you do it often), you may use my script `mountimg` to do everything for you. Just get it from https://github.com/AlexanderAmelkin/mountimg
and use like this:

```
mountimg /media/external_media/sda.img 2 /media/sda_image
```

You may as well specify filesystem type and any other additional mount options if you like:

```
mountimg /media/external_media/sda.img 2 /media/sda_image -t vfat -o codepage=866,iocharset=utf-8
```

When you're done with the partition, simply `umount` it:

```
umount /media/sda_image
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a user-friendly and interactive way that requires that the excellent `fzf` utility is installed, as well as `sudo`.

First add this function to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```sh
pmount() { sudo mount -o loop,offset=$(($(sudo fdisk -lu "$1" | sed -n '/^Device/,/^$/p' | tail -n+2 | fzf | sed -E -e 's/[[:blank:]]+/ /g' | cut -d' ' -f2- | sed 's@^[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*@\1@') * 512)) "$1" "$2"; }
```

Then reload your shell (or type `$SHELL`).

You can then mount `.img` files with this command:

```sh
pmount my.img /mnt
```

A list pops up where you can select which permision you wish to mount, using the arrow keys and then pressing return.

[image]

Unmount with `sudo umount /mnt`.

Comment: This is great! In my case one of my partitions had an entry in the BOOT (i.e. the second) column, so using `cut -f2` didn't work to calculate $START. To get around this, if your version of fdisk has the -o option, then you can extract the Start column easily with `fdisk -l -o Start ${IMG_FILE}`. My final, scriptable version of calculating $START (without the interactive `fzf`) is `fdisk -l -o Start ${IMG_FILE} | tail -n +9 | head -n${PARTITION_NUMBER} | tail -n1`

Comment: Thanks for the input, Nick Crews. I updated the script so that it is now more robust (looks for the first number after the partition name).

Answer (score 0):

**How do I open / mount my ISO file when normal methods throw this error?
`wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error`.
I tried several methods but they all fail somehow.**

I'm actually answering this problem ([Unable to mount an ISO file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053554/unable-to-mount-an-iso-file)), which problem I also have, and have just solved, but the original question has been closed, and refers to this question, even though they seem different.

I feel that curators often close questions for indecipherable reasons, however, I don't have any choice but to use the closure and reference given. If it's wrong, perhaps the previous question can be re-opened, and this answer put there, where I'd like it to be? Since this user edited the original question, I suspect he might have been the one to close the original: https://askubuntu.com/users/301745/wjandrea

Anyway, leaving the filing issues behind, here's an example of trying to mount the ISO:

```
$ sudo mount -o ro,loop -t iso9660 nero.iso /mnt
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I called the ISO `nero.iso` because using the `file` command revealed the ISO is an artifact of the "Nero" CD Burning software, not that that helps any:

```
$ sudo file nero.iso
nero.iso: Nero CD image at 0x4B000 UDF filesystem data (version 1.5) 'nero'
```

After trying a few different things I came across a reference to the software `iat` which says it "converts many CD-ROM image formats to iso9660". Woah. It immediately, and effortlessly, works:

```
$ sudo apt install iat
$ man iat
$ iat nero.iso out.iso
Iso9660 Analyzer Tool v0.1.3 by Salvatore Santagati
Licensed under GPL v2 or later

Detect Signature ISO9660 START at 339968
Detect Signature ISO9660 END at 342016

 Image offset start at 307200
 Sector header 0 bit
 Sector ECC 0 bit
 Block 2048
Done
```

Really?
Now the mount command silently completes:

```
$ sudo mount -o ro,loop out.iso /mnt
```

And, Behold, the ISO is mounted, and Handbrake will now happily rip the content.

Thank you, Salvatore Santagati. I've always liked coffee... and ice-cream.

I hope anyone else with this problem is able to follow the reference from the previous question and find this answer despite the obscure filing!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a simple FUSE application to do this without the need for root - source here: https://gist.github.com/tchatow/7751287f218a0cc39b2038a8e04c704d

Usage: `main -i image.img mountpoint`. Tested on GPT formatted image.