# Mount *.img ( dd-rescued image file)

Tags: mount, external-hdd, dd

I have recovered 1TB external hard disk using DD-Rescue-GUI. The image is stored in a 2TB external hard disk. I tried to mount it but could not succeed. I also tried the solution in the [Mounting Disk Image in Raw format](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483009/mounting-disk-image-in-raw-format), and getting the below result.

In the below script, the parameter for `-o` in the line `sudo losetup -o 991369929728` is calculated as per the above link, i.e., `512 bytes * Starting sector = 512 * 1936269394 = 991369929728`

```
rauf@rauf-Latitude-E5420:~$ sudo fdisk -lu /media/rauf/My\ Passport/Old\ 1\ TB\ Disk/onetb.img
[sudo] password for rauf: 
Disk /media/rauf/My Passport/Old 1 TB Disk/onetb.img: 931.49 GiB, 1000169537536 bytes, 1953456128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6e697373`

Device                                           Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/media/rauf/My Passport/Old 1 TB Disk/onetb.img1      1936269394 3772285809 1836016416 875.5G 4f QNX4.x 3rd part
/media/rauf/My Passport/Old 1 TB Disk/onetb.img2      1917848077 2462285169  544437093 259.6G 73 unknown
/media/rauf/My Passport/Old 1 TB Disk/onetb.img3      1818575915 2362751050  544175136 259.5G 2b unknown
/media/rauf/My Passport/Old 1 TB Disk/onetb.img4      2844524554 2844579527      54974  26.9M 61 SpeedStor

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
rauf@rauf-Latitude-E5420:~$ sudo losetup -o 991369929728 /media/rauf/My\ Passport/Old\ 1\ TB\ Disk/onetb.img
losetup: /media/rauf/My Passport/Old 1 TB Disk/onetb.img: failed to use device: No such device
rauf@rauf-Latitude-E5420:~$ sudo losetup -o 991369929728 /media/rauf/My\ Passport/Old\ 1\ TB\ Disk/onetb.img
losetup: /media/rauf/My Passport/Old 1 TB Disk/onetb.img: failed to use device: No such device
rauf@rauf-Latitude-E5420:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`kpartx`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/kpartx) utility.

Attach the partitions to loop-devices with:

```
sudo kpartx -a -v onetb.img
```

and then use devices from `/dev/mapper/...`.

Comment: I'm  receiving..........rauf@rauf-Latitude-E5420:/media/rauf/My Passport/Old 1 TB Disk$ sudo kpartx -a -v onetb.img
[sudo] password for rauf: 
device-mapper: reload ioctl on loop13p1  failed: Invalid argument
create/reload failed on loop13p1
device-mapper: reload ioctl on loop13p2  failed: Invalid argument
create/reload failed on loop13p2
device-mapper: reload ioctl on loop13p3  failed: Invalid argument
create/reload failed on loop13p3
device-mapper: reload ioctl on loop13p4  failed: Invalid argument
create/reload failed on loop13p4

Comment: Are you sure that the backup file is correct? All partitions types like  *QNX4.x 3rd part*, *unknown* and *SpeedStor* are strange. I would recommend to make a copy of this backup file and analyze it with [R-Studio](https://www.r-studio.com/) for the best possible results.

Comment: Will copying this onetb.img to another copy suffice or I need to create another disk using R-Studio. I have created the file using DD-Recue GUI. It took two days to finish. I don't know if I can ask software recommendation here ( usually I avoid it). But if I get a consistent open source recovery software, it will be great.