# How to mount "nested" NTFS partitions (two NTFS partitions within /dev/sda6)

Tags: partitioning, mount, virtualbox, ntfs

On my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system I have a partition **/dev/sda6** in which Windows 10 has created two NTFS partitions. This is because I am using `VirtualBox` to run Windows as a guest OS on the Ubuntu host, and I have assigned /dev/sda6 to VirtualBox so that Windows can use it directly (as opposed to a file on the host that VB virtualizes as a disk). To clarify, I do not use dual-boot, just VB to run Windows as a guest OS on the Linux host.

I would like to mount the Windows partitions on the Linux host (with Windows and VB completely shut down, of course) but I can't do that as per usual, since /dev/sda6 is not an NTFS partition; Windows has made its own partitions in there.

If I point `fdisk` at /dev/sda6 and use the 'p' command to print the partition table, output is as follows:

```
fdisk /dev/sda6

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.31.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda6: 254.9 GiB, 273655995904 bytes, 534484367 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa30ee8b2

Device      Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda6p1 *       2048   1126399   1124352   549M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6p2      1126400 534480895 533354496 254.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

This is consistent with what Windows considers its own partition table (within /dev/sda6) to be.

So I need to mount /dev/sda6p1 and dev/sda6p2 as NTFS partitions. However, there is only a /dev/sda6 special file; /dev/sda6p1 and /dev/sda6p2 do not exist. (This makes sense since the Linux host is agnostic as to what happens within the virtualized Windows environment).

I've looked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678546/is-there-a-way-to-allow-nested-partition-tables) and at the mknod manpage, since I suspect I need to create the required special file in question, but I'm not sure how to associate these special files with the respective NTFS partitions within /dev/sda6.

How do I access /dev/sda6p1 and /dev/sda6p2 to mount them?

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/a/483011/158442

Comment: Yep. That worked. I'm getting errors about an unclean NTFS system but that's fixable. Tnx!