# Mount full disk image

Tags: mount, partitioning, fdisk, disk-image

I have a small collection of disk images that were made of entire disks. They were made as physical images, by which I mean that the device file was supplied without a side specified – i.e. `dd if=/dev/disk3 of=~/Desktop/image.001` rather than say `dd if=/dev/disk3s1 of=~/Desktop/image.001` to image the volume on the disk.

I am having trouble mounting these images now. I understand that when mounting physical disk images you must specify a byte offset (obtained perhaps using fdisk). However when I run `fdisk -lu ~/Desktop/image.001` it tells me that the offset is 1 (512 bytes)?? This seams improbable, and when mounting via the means laid out [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device), it tells me "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock…" "missing codepage or helper program…"

What am I doing wrong?? How can I mount these images? There is only one volume on the partition, and it contains an Ext2 filesystem. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `man fdisk` says, about `-u`: `When  listing partition tables, show sizes in 'sectors' or in 'cylinders'.  The default is to show sizes in sectors.`. Are you sure you have the correct sector size? If you had an incorrect sector size, this exact problem would happen.