# How to mount a compressed disk image?

Tags: partitioning, mount, backup, dd, disk-image

If I make a disk image and **compress** it with gzip/xz/etc is there a way to mount it directly without first uncompressing it?

Say I've used

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdc1 | gzip -9 > image1.dd.gz
```

how can I mount the original image, without creating an uncompressed copy first?

Or I've used

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdc | gzip -9 > wholedisk.dd.gz
```

and the disk has multiple partitions, would that make it any harder?

With an uncompressed image of a whole disk then using `kpartx` or newer versions of `losetup` with it's `-P` flag should create a loop for each partition.

But is there a way to mount/losetup/read the compressed image?

If it won't work for gzip/xz, is there any compression method this would work for?

---

## *Note on duplicate Q*

The currently suggested duplicate

- [Mount single partition from image of entire disk (device)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69363) , while being an excellent useful Q

**DOES NOT USE COMPRESSION**, and ***IS NOT A DUPLICATE***.

`mount` will not mount a compressed image by itself.

Comment: I can tell you that it definitely is possible. But I can't tell you how atm because the instructions are on 2 external HDD and right now I have access to neither but I want to let you know that it works. I'll come back with an answer when I have one (and no one else posted one until then).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mount single partition from image of entire disk (device)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device)

Comment: @UTF-8 That's encouraging, thanks. FYI, original goal is to make a smaller backup of a drive/partition that's nearly empty or has lots of easily compressible data, and be able to read it without writing a LOT of extra data or needing a ton of free space to extract it

Comment: See also https://major.io/2010/12/14/mounting-a-raw-partition-file-made-with-dd-or-dd_rescue-in-linux/

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Thanks, but those don't address the compression, afaik mount & losetup/kpartx don't automatically uncompress images.

Comment: Then you have answered your own question ;)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Pardon? Maybe I should clarify, mount *does not* automatically uncompress images, so this Q is not a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/69363 (maybe I missed the joke, hopefully uncompressing isn't the *only* answer :)

Comment: You have answered your own question. "Mount will not mount a compressed image" which is partially true, mount will mount a compressed image if you use squashfs. So you have to decompress it first QED. The question I linked tells you how to mount the partition(s) on the image.

Comment: @Xen2050 Don't get your hopes up to hear about the solution from me very soon. The earliest point in time I could go where those external HDDs are is in about a week. I'm currently extracting 3 compressed images myself because I need something stored on them and don't want to wait until then.

Comment: No rush, I'll wait. Maybe there's another creative solution that someone's been hiding, just waiting for a Q like this to answer. Thanks bodhi.zazen, I just found the `squashfs` method too (from google, the search here on AskUbuntu doesn't extend to other SE sites) and it looks like a good answer too, anyone who gave "just the facts" instructions in an answer here would at least get an upvote from me, maybe a check-mark if there's no other super answers after a while too.

Comment: Sorry, I probably was mistaken. I can't find any script doing that on my external hard drives.

Comment: There's an [answer over on Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138081/37589) that says [nbdkit](https://github.com/libguestfs/nbdkit) & it's [xz plugin](https://github.com/libguestfs/nbdkit/blob/master/plugins/xz/nbdkit-xz-plugin.pod) can do this with xz compression, but getting it to work (installing / compiling the plugin?) has eluded me. I'd upvote & select correct an answer that showed (plain & simple steps) how to get it to work, especially if it worked with gzip too.

Comment: see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31669/is-it-possible-to-mount-a-gzip-compressed-dd-image-on-the-fly

Comment: If you're compressing a whole disk image, `-9` seems like a poor choice as it would unnecessarily slow down the compression.  `-3` is probably a sweet spot where it compresses nearly as well but it'll go much, much faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to get an NBD server  to "serve up" an un-compressed version of a .gz or .xz file. I'm not sure if it has to read the entire compressed file very often (only tested so far with small files in ram) but at least it works without having to extract a whole un-compressed copy.

## Viewing a gz / xz Compressed dd image "on-the-fly"

### 1 - Install nbdkit & client

```
apt install nbdkit nbd-client
```

### 2 *(Optional for testing only)* - Create demo "dd" style file - an empty 50M file with an ext filesystem & zip it

```
fallocate -l 50M 50m
mkfs.ext3 -v 50m
```

Then compress with either gzip or xz

```
gzip -vk9 50m
xz -v9k 50m
```

Note: An `xz` option of `--block-size=16MiB` should give better random access performance, but at the expense of less compression (maybe 1%?). See the [nbdkit's xz plugin description](https://github.com/libguestfs/nbdkit/blob/master/plugins/xz/nbdkit-xz-plugin.pod).

### 3 - Run server on COMPRESSED image

```
nbdkit -v --no-fork -i 127.0.0.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nbdkit/plugins/nbdkit-gzip-plugin.so file=~/Downloads/50m.gz
```

or for xz

```
nbdkit -v --no-fork -i 127.0.0.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nbdkit/plugins/nbdkit-xz-plugin.so file=~/Downloads/50m.xz
```

Apparently newer versions of ndbkit can specify `--filter=xz` instead of specifying a whole plugin path:

```
nbdkit -v --no-fork -i 127.0.0.1  --filter=xz file=~/Downloads/50m.xz
```

- The `--no-fork` tells the server *"Don't fork into the background"* so seeing possible error messages & killing it with CTRL-C is a little easier.
- `-v` may / will show too many status messages, especially when reading.

### 4 - Run client (in another terminal/window)

```
sudo nbd-client -nofork 127.0.0.1 10809 /dev/nbd0
```

The `-nofork` is similar to `-no-fork` above, but I could *not* kill the client with CTRL-C, `kill <pid>`, or `sudo kill <pid>`. Ending the server with CTRL-C stopped both server & client.

### 5 - Observe that `/dev/nbd0` is now identical to UN-COMPRESSED image

```
$ sudo diff -s /dev/nbd0 ~/Downloads/50m
Files /dev/nbd0 and /home/user/Downloads/50m are identical
```

`/dev/nbd0` can now be used just like the uncompressed image; mounted, read/copy with `dd`, or use `kpartx`, `partprobe`, `vgscan` / `vgchange`, etc!

<sub>Thanks to [Cristian Ciupitu on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138081/37589), though it took a little more digging to find the plugin & get everything going together.</sub>

Comment: On Fedora 31 `nbdkit -v --no-fork -i 127.0.0.1 --filter=xz file ~/Downloads/50m.xz` worked great with the same client command

Comment: On Ubuntu xenial 16.04 LTS `nbdkit 1.1.11 ` uses old NBD protocol, which differs from new NBD protocol, used in `nbd-client 3.13`, but you ca use nbd-client version before 3.10, e.g. `nbd-client 3.8 from Ubuntu precise 12.04 old LTS` [use old versions only locally for security!]

Comment: Simply specifying `xz` in place of `/usr/lib/.../nbdkit-xz-plugin.so` works great and lets it pick `x86_64-linux-gnu` or `i386-linux-gnu` automatically.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 20.04 (nbdkit v1.16.2), the `nbdkit-xz-plugin.so` [file is missing](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/nbdkit/filelist). So, probably one should use `--filter=xz` as specified by @EkriirkE. Whereas, I simply downloaded the `deb` for [nbdkit for Debian Buster](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/nbdkit), extracted the plugin from it and used it, and that worked too.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `squashfs` to compress disk images and then mount them.

## Create the disk image

If you haven't got a disk image yet use `dd` to create one:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/tmp/sda1.img bs=4M
```

## Compress the image with squashfs

Install `squashfs`:

```
apt-get install squashfs-tools
```

Compress the image:

```
mksquashfs /tmp/sda1.img /tmp/sda1.squash.img
```

## Or Stream the compression (don't need a temporary dd file)

```
mkdir empty-dir
mksquashfs empty-dir squash.img -p 'sda_backup.img f 444 root root dd if=/dev/sda bs=4M'
```

Compliments to [terminator14 at UbuntuForums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2240493&s=684aca08f7f0b380fb5faefca5d8730c&p=13103696#post13103696). Definitions/Explanations:

- **`empty-dir`** - "source" dir. Basically in our case, just an empty dir to satisfy mksquashfs' input arg format
- **`squash.img`** - the destination and filename of the output squashfs file
- **`sda_backup.img`** - the name of the dd backup INSIDE the squashfs file
- **`f`** - specifies that sda_backup.img is a regular file (as opposed to a directory, block device, or char device)
- **`444`** - permissions of the sda_backup.img file inside the squashfs image
- **`root root`** - UID and GID for the sda_backup.img file inside the squashfs image. Can be specified by decimal numbers, or by name
- **`dd if=/dev/sda bs=4M`** - the dd command used to read the device we want backed up

## Mount the image

First mount the `squashfs` image:

```
mkdir /mnt/squash
mount /tmp/sda1.squash.img /mnt/squash
```

This will present the un-compressed disk image for you to mount:

```
mkdir /mnt/sda1
mount /mnt/squash/sda1.img /mnt/sda1
```

Or if it's a full drive image (partitioned) you could use `losetup` to attach the dd image to a loop device (possibly optional) and then `kpartx -a` or `partprobe` to find & separate the partitions to separate devices, or even `vgscan` / `vgchange -ay` if there's LVM.

Comment: I added some on-the-fly squashfs info, to avoid needing a temporary plain dd file. Great answer with squashfs, just doesn't do the more pipe-friendly xz/gz formats

Comment: Would that somehow work with a full disk image containing multiple partitions as well?

Comment: See here for full disk: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31669/is-it-possible-to-mount-a-gzip-compressed-dd-image-on-the-fly

Comment: Depending on the filesystem type, mounting may require the `ro,noload` options, like so: `mount -o ro,noload /mnt/squash/sda1.img /mnt/sda1`