# how to change fat partition label on disk image file?

Tags: partitioning, fat32, disk-image

the command:

`sudo mlabel -i /dev/sdb1 ::my_external`

meant to apply the new label `my_external` for the `/dev/sdb1` drive or partition, if only it's a separate device one. what would be the command for changing one of the partitions label name on the disk image file?

it would be very nice to get automation based solution as to be used for disk image generation recipes, scripts, etc.

Comment: I think it is easiest to use **`gparted`**, which has a graphical user interface.

Comment: @sudodus that does not work well with the automation requirement.

Comment: @ChristofferSoop, You are right, but the request for automation was added after my comment. Please add your own solution, if you have one. On the oither hand, if you are looking for help, it is better to **create an own question**, where you describe your problem (and maybe link to this question).

Comment: @sudodus sorry, did not mean any harm - just thought the comment a bit incongruous but I did not the question was changed after you provided it. And no I don't have a solution to offer, I am actually asking the same question.

Comment: @ChristofferSoop, I still think the best alternative is to ask an own question, where you describe what you have and what help you need. - But maybe [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022633/mount-dd-image-for-my-usb/1102212#1102212) may help you start in the right direction (along with the answer here by Harry Tsai).

Comment: @sudodus well, I came to this question because of what I am asking in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1385007/1000986), so already done. Also did some research on editing filesystems dumped to image files on the way here but it would appear that it is not really feasible without mounting the image as a loopback device as indicated by the only answer to this question - but thanks for the link all the same!

Answer (score 2):

You can map the partitions of a disk image through the loop device, as described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209566/how-to-format-a-partition-inside-of-an-img-file#answer-209586).

```
sudo losetup --partscan --show --find binary.img
```

Use `blkid` to see which device name your partition was assigned (typ. `/dev/loop0p1`) as described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14165/list-partition-labels-from-the-command-line#answer-260363).

```
sudo blkid
```