# Mounting all partitions in a disk image

Tags: mount, encryption, partitioning, luks

Trying to mount all partitions of a disk image.

I can only mount the first partition, but unable to mount the other 2 partitions.

```
userone@desktop:/media/userone/BACKUP$ sudo fdisk -lu 16-04-desktop.iso 
Disk 16-04-desktop.iso: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x73ce36a2

Device             Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
16-04-desktop.iso1 *       2048    999423    997376  487M 83 Linux
16-04-desktop.iso2      1001470 125044735 124043266 59.2G  5 Extended
16-04-desktop.iso5      1001472 125044735 124043264 59.2G 83 Linux
userone@desktop:/media/userone/BACKUP$ sudo losetup -o 1048576 /dev/loop0 16-04-desktop.iso
losetup: 16-04-desktop.iso: failed to set up loop device: Device or resource busy
userone@desktop:/media/userone/BACKUP$ sudo losetup -o 1048576 /dev/loop20 16-04-desktop.iso
userone@desktop:/media/userone/BACKUP$ sudo losetup -o 512752640 /dev/loop21 16-04-desktop.iso
userone@desktop:/media/userone/BACKUP$ sudo losetup -o 512753664 /dev/loop22 16-04-desktop.iso
userone@desktop:/media/userone/BACKUP$ sudo mount /dev/loop20 ~/Desktop/1
userone@desktop:/media/userone/BACKUP$ sudo mount /dev/loop21 ~/Desktop/2
mount: /home/userone/Desktop/2: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop21, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
userone@desktop:/media/userone/BACKUP$ sudo mount /dev/loop22 ~/Desktop/3
mount: /home/userone/Desktop/3: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'.
userone@desktop:/media/userone/BACKUP$
```

How do I mount the other 2 partitions?

Answer (score 1):

### Mounting partitions in a cloned image of a drive

- You should be able to mount all primary and logical partitions, for example with `kpartx`, in your case it seems to be partition #1 and partition #5.
- You cannot mount an extended partition. It is a container for logical partitions (inside the extended partition).
- There is a detailed description in my answer to a similar question,

  [Mount dd image for my USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022633/mount-dd-image-for-my-usb/1102212#1102212)

### Workaround

Unless someone can show how to mount a drive or partition with encryption, for example an Ubuntu 'encrypted disk', LVM with encryption, I can suggest the following workaround.

- Get a new drive that is big enough, at least as big as the uncompressed image file and clone from the image file to the new drive.
- If things work well, you can replace the old drive and boot from the new drive.
- Otherwise you should be able to mount the partitions, even if it is more complicated due to the encryption.

  [Booting into an ISO full drive backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102187/booting-into-an-iso-full-drive-backup/1102230#1102230)

Comment: @Melebius, You are right. I have not tested mounting file systems in an image of an encrypted drive. I will delete my answer, if you think I should.

Comment: @Melebius, I added a work around :-/