# No return when trying to access the root directory

Tags: root, dd, disk-image, fat32

I have a fat16 I am currently trying to look at the root directory, but I'm getting little to no return with the following command:

```
sudo dd if=Project1.dd bs=512 | hexdump -C -s $(( 2132*512 )) -n $(( 32*512 ))
```

The fat in question begins at 2048, so I am jumping to 2132 (where I assume the root directory begins), but I am getting the following return and nothing else:

```
0010a800 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
*
0010e800
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or perhaps point out what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mount dd image for my USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022633/mount-dd-image-for-my-usb)

Comment: N0bert, let me look it over to see. I have it mounted already from what I can tell, it just isn't opening the root file like it should.