# Unable to mount an ISO file

Tags: 16.04, mount, iso

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

When I try to mount an ISO file using:

1. Right click the file and select [Open With] > [Archive Mounter]
2. Right click the file and select [Open With] > [Disk Image Mounter]
3. [gnome-disk-utility] > [Disks] > [Attach Disk Image]
4. `sudo mount -o loop '/media/oshirowanen/250GB.iso' /media/iso`

I get the following error message for attempts 1, 2, 3, and 4:

```
Unable to access “New Volume”
Error mounting /dev/loop10p1 at /media/oshirowanen/New Volume: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/loop10p1" "/media/oshirowanen/New Volume"' exited with non-zero exit status 21: ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Permission denied
Failed to sync device /dev/loop10p1: Input/output error
Failed to close volume /dev/loop10p1: Input/output error
```

Anyone know how to resolve this?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

5. `sudo mount -o ro,loop /media/oshirowanen/250GB.iso /media/iso`

The following error is given for attempt 5:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop12,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

---

**Possible useful info**

The `iso` was created from an `ntfs` drive using the command

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sde | pv | sudo dd if=/media/oshirowanen/250GB.iso
```

Comment: Are you an admin on the system? If so, do you get permission errors for any other typical admin activity?

Comment: @user535733, I don't  use the computer as an admin for normal stuff, I usually use `sudo` if I want to do something with elevated privileges.  I've just tried `sudo aptitude update`, and it worked fine without any errors.

Comment: Can you please try ```sudo mount -o ro,loop /media/oshirowanen/250GB.iso /media/iso```

Comment: @AmithKK, I've added the details of your suggestion to the question above as `attempt 5`.

Comment: I have a feeling because you dd the WHOLE drive, and not just a partition, the MBR (or GPT) is there as well. As such, you might find the right way of mounting it here: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device)

Answer (score 1):

First of all create directory:

```
sudo mkdir /media/iso
```

Check if your image has a boot sector:

```
sudo file /media/oshirowanen/250GB.iso
```

If your drive image has a boot sector, issue the command in terminal:

```
sudo fdisk /media/oshirowanen/250GB.iso
```

Find in the table in `Start` column number, let it be `64` for example. Multiply this number by `512` (sector size), i.e. `64x512=32768`. And finally mount your image with `offset` option:

```
sudo mount -o loop,offset=32768 /media/oshirowanen/250GB.iso /media/iso
```