# Mount an image created by adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk*: "wrong fs type"

Tags: mount, android, ext4, adb, loop-device

With the command below, I thought I had rescued the content of my broken Android phone:

```
adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0p28 mmcblk0p28.img
```

Unfortunately my attempt to mount it on Ubuntu fails:

```
sudo mount -o loop mmcblk0p28.img /mnt/
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop20, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I think it is ext4. Photorec (set up for ext) successfully outputs all of my files, but with random filenames so I still want to mount the image.

After reading the [highest-voted answer at a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/69447/4066) I tried fdisk but it does not show partition info, probably because I pulled only a single partition:

```
$ sudo fdisk -lu mmcblk0p28.img
Disk mmcblk0p28.img: 6.2 GiB, 6654066688 bytes, 12996224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Another answer suggests losetup, when I run `sudo losetup -Pf mmcblk0p28.img` it does not output anything nor does it mount anything.

What is the correct command?

Or is my image somehow corrupt?