# My Encore N300 wireless usb doesn't connect, any workarounds?

Tags: wireless

I decided to wipe Windows 7 and made a full installation.

Everything works great but for a Encore N300 wireless usb dongle that I use on my desktop. Ubuntu seems to recognize it and I can browse the available networks, but I can connect to any of them. I was told that I should download its drivers, and so I did it, but I don't know how to install them.

Please, I'd like to know if my connectivity problem is really a driver issue or some other thing.

Comment: Looks like this dongle uses the rtl8192cu driver.

Comment: **Note:** This question was originally posted in Spanish and then translated by a human. The untranslated original text is available [here](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/159107/1)

Answer (score 1):

Can you open a terminal (search for terminal in dash) and type these two commands:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8192cu
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu swenc=1
```

Afterwards try to connect to a network. If it works you need to make it permanent, please check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51226/how-to-add-kernel-module-parameters).

It will load the driver with a new value for the swenc parameter. I have no idea of what it does, but it seems to help sometimes.

---

¿Puedes abrir un terminal (búscalo en el dash), y escribe estos dos comandos (pulsa enter al final de cada linea)?

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8192cu
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu swenc=1
```

Después, intenta conectarte otra vez, Si funciona sigue el enlace de arriba para hacer el cambio permanente.

Comment: hola javier gracias por responder probe lo que me dijistes y no ha habido cambios me fije en el  terminal que controlador tengo y me dice 8178 realteksemiconductor

Comment: Pues entonces, excepto instalar los drivers de Realtek, que es relativamente complejo no se me ocurre nada. A ver si alguien más tiene alguna idea.

Comment: gracias javier dde todas maneras imaginaba que instalar los draiver de realtek no es nada sencillo asi que si consig

Comment: so consigo un tutorial lo intentare