# Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet, connection

I have dual booted my Windows 8 laptop with Ubuntu 14.04. The wifi driver is Realtek rtl8723be. It didn't use to work but I updated the kernel to 3.18 and reinstalled the driver and that seemed to solve the problem for a few hours. Then it would be connected for around 30 minutes and then the connection would stop, even though the icon on the system tray would still indicate it's connected. The only thing that works is restarting the computer but then, again, after 30 minutes the connection stops.

Comment: [My answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/673826/450605) to the question [My wifi drops the connection after a few minutes realtek8723be](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632719/my-wifi-drops-the-connection-after-a-few-minutes-realtek8723be) should help.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-8723be-wireless-card-to-work

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593848/254422

Answer (score 60):

I was having these problem with rtl8723be on linux mint 17, and mint17.1. The same procedure should work on ubuntu 14.04 and derivates.

I had to install new module for realtek wifi cards where they solved the constant disconnects:

- install required packages

  ```
  sudo apt-get install build-essential git
  ```
- git clone new realtek wifi modules

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/
  ```
- enter the directory

  ```
  cd rtlwifi_new
  ```
- build it

  ```
  make
  ```
- install

  ```
  sudo make install
  ```

Now you can reboot or unload/load modules

- unload modules

  ```
  sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
  ```
- load new module

  ```
  sudo modprobe rtl8723be
  ```
- if it still doesn't work, try the solution from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632719/my-wifi-drops-the-connection-after-a-few-minutes-realtek8723be)

  ```
  echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
  ```

Note: After each kernel update, you need to rebuild the modules. That is,

After every kernel update:

```
cd rtlwifi_new
```

Clean previous builds

```
make clean
```

Update git repository

```
git pull
```

Compile

```
make clean && make
```

Install

```
sudo make install
```

reboot or unload/load modules

EDIT: It seems as of kernel 4.17 kernel APIs have changed: 
Note: If your kernel is 4.17 or newer, AND your card is not an RTL8723DE, then you should NOT be using the external driver. The built-in one is the same.
source: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/

Comment: This works perfectly (Lenovo B40, Ubuntu 14.04) . Thanks.

Comment: This also worked for a Gigabyte P15 Laptop, the only difference being the "kernel-headers" package wasnt found or required for Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit version.

Comment: Thank you for the info!
I'll also note that my laptop is HP 470G2.

Comment: didn't need to add options to the wifi config the new drivers work great.

Comment: It's work on HP Pro Book 430 G2

Comment: It's not working for me. I got modprobe: error: could not insert 'rtl8723be': required key not available

Comment: This solves the same problem on 16.04 kernel 4.4

Comment: My problem was the Wi-Fi networks were not showing at all, so i had to follow the below steps till `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` then,

`sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be`
`sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1` or `sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2`

After doing this it would list the Wi-Fi signals in the menu.

Comment: Thank you Sriram Kannan. 
This is well explained on the GitHub page of rtlwifi_new by its creator lwfinger.
So for anyone with the same problem, read the following:
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/88

Comment: worked like charm on HP ProBook 470 G3, Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I would upvote, but the answer needs modification, because it doesn't work as expected with modern kernels: unsigned module can't be loaded, so after applying instructions I got my wifi disabled completely.

Comment: You should read carefully before applying modules:
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/
It clearly states: "IF YOU RUN UBUNTU, YOU CAN BE ASSURED THAT THE APIs HAVE CHANGED. NO, I WILL NOT MODIFY THE SOURCE FOR YOU. YOU ARE ON YOUR OWN!!!!!" :)
Thanks for the comment tho, I will update the Answer.

Answer (score 11):

My friend's HP laptop wouldn't display the available Wi-Fi networks.

So I followed the steps from [Miodrag Prelec's  answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/593015/72251) till `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`

Then, I did

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
```

Then either of:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

(whichever works)

After doing this it would list the Wi-Fi signals in the menu.

So I added these lines to `/etc/rc.local` (above `exit 0`) so that it would run each time my laptop boots up.

```
sleep 10
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

Note: change `ant_sel=1` to `ant_sel=2` if required.

[source](http://www.linuxlinx.com/2016/05/install-realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-driver-ubuntu-linuxmint.html)

Comment: `sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2`
fixed it! I cannot thank you enough bro! If you were in my country, I would buy you a drink. 

I literally spent 2 months+ trying to make my friend's wifi on ubuntu work. While Realtek's driver was feeling like a curse, your solution is like a blessing.

Comment: @RifazNahiyan I'm glad it helped. I spent 5 hours trying to make WiFi work on my friend's Ubuntu, then found a post (I added the source) mentioning `ant_sel=1` and it solved the problem. All thanks to LinuxLinx

Comment: «I added these lines to `/etc/rc.local`» Your example shows a script that will **delay boot by 10 seconds.** A cleaner alternative is to [set up a kernel module parameter](http://askubuntu.com/a/51250/271) by adding for instance `rtl8723be.ant_sel=2` after `quiet splash` in `/etc/default/grub` and then issuing `sudo update-grub`. :)

Comment: Dude, After 1 year, I found this solution. Tried everything. but could not make it work. Your solution worked like a charm! Thanks :) P.S. - Commenting  while connected to a wifi n/w.:)

Answer (score 9):

Run the following command in terminal

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

as this will disable some of the power management of the card and usually helps.

And then you need to reboot or manually reload the driver

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be
```

This was found in [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243691&p=13119513#post13119513). Varunendra is very good troubleshooting the realtek cards.

Comment: I tried this, but it made me unable to connect at all. Only after deleting `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` and restarting was I able to get online again.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar situation, I took the suggestions available on various sites, and created this script which works for me.
[Here it is on GitHub](https://github.com/tarunbatra/fixRTL8723BE)

To clone the repo, run:

```
git clone https://github.com/tarunbatra/fixRTL8723BE
```

`cd` to the project root, then run `bash install.sh`. Here's the script for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin env bash

REPO="https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new"
CONFIG_DIR=`pwd`

checkGit() {
  if git --version  &> /dev/null; then
    echo "Git found"
  else
    echo "Git not found"
  fi
}

installGit() {
  echo "Installing git\n"
  sudo apt-get install git >> /dev/null
}

cloneRepo() {
  echo "Downloading latest drivers from $REPO"
  if git clone $REPO /tmp/rtlwifi_new_$$; then
    echo "Drivers downloaded successfully"
  else
    echo "Download couldn't be completed. Exiting"
    exit 1
  fi
}

installDrivers() {
  cd /tmp/rtlwifi_new_$$ || (echo "Drivers not found"; exit 1)
  echo "Building drivers"
  if make && sudo make install; then
    echo "Drivers built successfully"
  else
    echo "Drivers couldn't be built. Exiting"
    exit 1
  fi
}
configureWiFi() {
  echo "Configuring the WiFi settings"
  cd $1
  if (cat ./setup.conf  | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf); then
    echo "WiFi settings configured"
  else
    echo "Wifi settings couldn't be configured"
  fi
}

restartWiFi() {
  echo "Restarting WiFi"
  if sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be && sudo modprobe rtl8723be; then
    echo "WiFi restarted"
  else
    echo "Couldn't restart WiFi"
  fi
}

echo "Fixing Wifi"
checkGit || installGit
cloneRepo $REPO
installDrivers
configureWiFi $CONFIG_DIR
restartWiFi
echo "Your WiFi is fixed. Enjoy!"
echo "If this doen't help, try changing rtl8723be.conf and repeating the process"
exit 0
```

Comment: I tried this solution but there is still a ? sign on my wifi  and it drops and also is slow

Comment: @MahdiYounesi what is the output of the script?

Comment: The output  was your echos in script, I ended up buying a USB wireless adapter for 10$ now I'm good