# Wireless not working Ubuntu 14.04 Lenovo g50

Tags: 14.04, wireless, lenovo

since I installed ubuntu on my lenovo I can only get wireless internet for about 5 minutes after I restart my computer, and then it just stops responding. My network security is WEP and ethernet connection is good. I'd be great to fix this issue.

Comment: Neither **WEP** or **WPA** is wireless network **security**, and should NOT be used **EVER**. *Use either **WPA2** or (preferably) **EAP/RADIUS** authentication.*

Comment: To assist you, you need to provide more details. What is the output from **`lsusb`**, that relates to the Wireless device? Or provide details from **`sudo lshw`** that identify the wireless chipset.

Comment: @david6 lsusb is `Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:055d Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
`

Comment: Device ID **0bda:b728** suggests you should try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been answered before.

First, open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>), then type the following:

```
    rfkill list
```

If it shows up to be softblocked, then try:

```
    rfkill unblock all
```

If it shows up to be hardblocked and any and all wireless switches on your laptop are ON, then there is a conflict between Linux and your BIOS. I have such a conflict on my own Toshiba Satellite, and solved it with the following steps:

First, make sure your Wi-Fi (or any wireless) switch is ON before booting. The BIOS will see it on and leave it that way. Never use 'Fn + F8' or any other methods to turn off the wireless. Use Ubuntu's built-in soft methods instead - that is, by clicking on the icon in the top-left of your screen.

Comment: `0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
` rfkill list output