# The wifi is not working on my HP Pavilion x360 with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet, connection

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 10 but the wifi hasn't worked once since installation. However, it works fine in Windows.

I made sure that on Windows the wifi is turned on. And I've already tried this solution [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04).

When I go to System Settings->Network and try to turn the Wireless ON it immediately turns OFF and doesn't show any wifi networks.

The wireless info is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13347247/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have both of the helper modules loaded: `hp-wmi` and `acer-wmi`. I think you need one but not both. Let's see if your wireless switch properly responds if you remove the most likely candidate:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r acer-wmi
modprobe hp-wmi
exit
```

If this is effective, remove the previously ineffective blacklist:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Remove the incorrect line: `blacklist hp-wmi`, save and close the text editor.

Comment: The switch still doesn't work. http://paste.ubuntu.com/13348214/

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: You nailed it! It works like a charm. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The wireless info shows that in `rfkill` output you have

```
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Therefore run  `sudo rfkill unblock all`

Comment: I ran it again but still remains the same. http://paste.ubuntu.com/13348214/