# Wifi on HP Stream doesn't recognise any networks

Tags: 14.04, wireless, hp, realtek-wireless

Alright, so I just got an HP Stream 13 for Christmas, and windows 10 was being very slow, so I decided to install Ubuntu. However Wifi doesn't recognise any networks, what do I do, I am freaking out, I am a Linux noob.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 2280 (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 21)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 2284 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22c8 (rev 21)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22ce (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 2292 (rev 21)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

UPDATE: Okay, I installed the driver using this tutorial [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04) and I saw my networks for a few seconds, but when I tried to connect I got an error. I don't remember what the message was.

Comment: Does Ubuntu atleast show you the Wifi connections?

Comment: Not at all, nothing

Comment: `02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter` - Its the driver for your wireless adapter.

Comment: Here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I have no way to get a temporary connection, can I download something on my windows pc?

Comment: Download this - https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/archive/master.zip

Comment: Then I just put it on my computer, run the command, and it works?

Comment: Wait you need to download two more things

Comment: Download build essential as per your architecture - http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/build-essential

Comment: Browse - packages.ubuntu.com/trusty and download the following packages - `dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.8 gcc gcc-4.8 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libdpkg-perl
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libitm1 libstdc++6-4.7-dev libtimedate-perl linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev`

Comment: Goto here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/allpackages and download all the above packages into one folder and then run `cd /path/to/the/folder && sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Comment: After you have installed everything, folkow the link i posted before

Comment: @DoctorRaichu - you need to edit your question with what you are being asked and what information you have found out.  Remember to delete your old comments - or just flag and we can do  a mass delete after you've incorporated all the information into your question.

Comment: Are you willing to disassemble the laptop?

Comment: Not really, no.

Comment: See [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](/q/974/175814) for methods to install the necessary packages for [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](/q/590414/175814) without a working network connection.

Answer (score 1):

HP has started to use only one antenna on some of their laptops as found [in this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2304607&page=2&p=13402744#post13402744) by Jerry Gorland who has a Stream 11 and a picture from [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/80) by modev32
[image: modev32 picture from lwfinger github]

Larry Finger stated that Realtek is working on code that will detect what connector the antenna is connected to but no timeline has been released

Comment: so what do I do?

Comment: You can either disassemble the laptop to change the antenna to the other connector or wait for Realtek to come up with a software solution

Comment: When I was running windows it worked fine

Comment: The Windows driver might be using both connectors or have the correct coding to use the one with the better reception.  Jerry Gorland also stated in the Ubuntuforums post that it worked fine in Windows.  I wanted to have a better answer but that is it for now