# What version of linux supports rtl8723be?

Tags: wireless

My laptop has this card, what should I do? What version of linux should I get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi on HP Stream doesn't recognise any networks](http://askubuntu.com/questions/713542/wifi-on-hp-stream-doesnt-recognise-any-networks)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is supported from linux 3.13 ....
 Install ubuntu 15.10 (which has kernel 4.2)

Comment: i did, didn't work

Comment: In that case, please [open a new question](/questions/ask) to ask for help with this particular problem, since it doesn't fit under the theme of your current question of "is it supported"? Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and include a link to the result in your new question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](/a/517964/175814), the Linux kernel includes a driver for the RTL8723BE wireless network adapter chipset since (at least) version 3.13, which is included in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Alternatively the most recent release 15.10 has a newer kernel version that should work just as well.

Comment: If I upgrade to the newest kernel 4.3.3 will it work?

Comment: This is unlikely to make a difference.

Comment: I have 4.4.9 and RTL8723BE works but Bluetooth is displayed as unknown and scanning devices has problem finding device names.

Comment: @dashesy: If you have a question please [open a new question](/questions/ask). The comment section is not the right place for questions or extended discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there were/are problems with the Wifi chipset RTL8723BE. Here is a link to my blog post describing couple of my attempts to solve this with different kernels:

https://artofcode.wordpress.com/2017/08/29/problems-with-wifi-signal-under-linux/

One conclusion: newest kernel doesn't automatically mean better support for this chipset.

It's not that bad if you can use antenna selection configuration. If I recall correctly this was the case with some kernels in versions 4.15.0-`X` where `X < 33`. With the kernel 4.15.0-33 you need to compile a kernel module which may be not obvious for less advanced users.

In worst case it was like that: antenna selection configuration was ignored and source code of an alternative kernel module was not compatible with the kernel...

The best is to try different Linux kernels using live versions.