# Driver download for RTL8723BE?

Tags: networking, drivers

I have a Dell Inspiron 13-7000 series, which has the RTL8723BE Realtek wireless chip. Wifi currently does not work on the computer, and it has no ethernet port, so I can't use terminal to download anything. Is there a standalone driver I can download on my Mac and put onto a flash drive and copy onto my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04? (Kernel is 3.19 if it matters)

Comment: If the Wi-Fi list is not showing in your laptop,
[check my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/856020/72251)

Answer (score 0):

Answered here:

[Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Also, if you head to GitHub you can see the files:

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/