# Wifi problem rtl8723be

Tags: wireless, drivers, internet, realtek

I have tried a lot of ways to make my WiFi connection stable and it is okay now for an hour. Solutions that I already tried:

1. Dedoimedo: [Fix for the Realtek RTL8723BE driver in Ubuntu Trusty](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-trusty-realtek.html)
2. Ask Ubuntu: [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04)
3. UbuntuForums: [RTL8723BE wifi dropping connection on Ubuntu 14.04](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243978)

The 2nd link helped me to install the drivers, `options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N`
helped to make the connection stable.

Problem: I can't access the internet through WiFi on the laptop, but it works on any other device. And I don't have any idea why.

If you need some additional information, please tell me.
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Comment: I have tried this, but now all my problems came back, will try one more time.
Thank you, @Pilot6!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. somewhere I found that we need to edit wifi network we are connected to and add 8.8.8.8 as dns. After that I was able to get Internet access.

Comment: It's strange - now my wifi is working ok, the only one problem is sometimes notebook cant see or connect to network, but on/off wifi fix this.

Comment: @Gleb Abroskin, didn't adding 8.8.8.8 as dns give you Internet access?? Did you down vote my answer??

Comment: no, I did not. And didnot try it, thanks for help!