# Ubuntu 14.04.3 slow internet, Toshiba Satellite L15W-B1208X with Intel Pentium N3700

Tags: networking, internet

I am brand new here, and while I've played around with Ubuntu before in a different machine, this is my first time on a UEFI machine. I've finally had enough with Windows 10, and have cut all ties now. I love the unity dash for my touchscreen, but I'm having this really annoying problem with my internet connection now. When I turn the computer it will work for a minute or two, then just die on me. I have checked around, and nothing I have found yet seems to work for me in particular.

So I've tried most of the relevant items I could find online, such as disabling 802.11n protocol, which gave me the error "module iwlwif is not currently loaded". I did the Debian avahi-daemon trick, and the Internet is so terrible I can't seem to download a different network manager to try that, or any different drivers. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the wireless adapters power management, and update the rtl8723be driver to the latest. 16.04 comes with this automatically I believe.

But when I was running 15.04lts, I followed this guide:
[Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04)

and it worked great. But the bigger issue you will run into is the hard freeze/lockups that happen at random with these Satellite L15W's (I have the same series, L15W-B1220), and these hard freezes are still present in 16.04lts. (sysreq REISUB does not work, cannot ssh into the device, the power must be cycled).