# RTL8723BE no module loaded after reboot

Tags: boot, wireless, windows, rtl8723be

When I'm trying to install windows driver for RTL8723BE on Lenovo IdeaPad100 wlan0 disappeared. I fixed it with this:

https://askubuntu.com/a/593015/531813

but after reboot I must type:

```
sudo modprobe -r 
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

How I can load modules on boot/why it is not loaded now?

Comment: You can try to add it to the file `/etc/rc.local` - removing the `sudo` bit.

Comment: Please edit to include result for `for i in /etc/modprobe.d/*; do echo $i; cat $i | grep rtl8723; done`

Comment: @Jeremy31 You are correct. The driver may be blacklisted by some previous installs.

Comment: Did you remove the windows driver?

Answer (score 1):

It should be fixed by

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

But still you will have to re-install the driver after kernel updates.

You can also install the same driver in DKMS format from a PPA.

https://askubuntu.com/a/635629/167850

This way you won't need to re-install it every time you upgrade a kernel.
But most likely you will need to uninstall the driver from git first.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding `rtl8723be` to `/etc/modules`

Comment: **Attention close voters:** Self-answer. VTC Q instead.