# Wifi option not seen

Tags: wireless, realtek, realtek-wireless

After I dual booted windows 10 with Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 the wifi range was reduced much.While I was trying to fix I run the command given below for unloading the module. .

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
```

After that the wifi menu is not displaying.What can be done?

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is given below.

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    DeviceName: Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11b/g/n 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
```

Comment: To get the module back, you can run `sudo modprobe rtl8723be` or reboot.

Comment: @Pilot6 sudo modprobe rtl8723be doesnt seem to be working .It gives the output:                                                                                                                   modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Required key not available

Comment: Please add new information to your question. You can [edit] it. Do not post it to comments.

Comment: And please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6....the output is added.

Comment: Please read the duplicate link, install the driver and probably you will need to use `ant_sel=2` parameter.

Comment: I will try that and let you know

Comment: It is not working.Wifi option is still not there.The driver is not installed.

Comment: What do you mean by "The driver is not installed"? Was there any error?

Comment: Apparantely no error.Still there is no wifi option avaiable.Only the wired connection  option is present in the Network Settings

Comment: "Required key not available" suggests a Secure Boot problem. Please try turning off secure boot in the BIOS.

Comment: @ chili555 thank you so much.I turned off secure boot mode in bios and it worked!!!

Answer (score 3):

I turned off secure boot option in bios and followed the steps given in the following link [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04][1]) posted by 3n3low and now wifi works perfectly fine.