# RTL8723BE PCIe wireless problem

Tags: drivers, wireless, rtl8723be

I have the wireless network card RTL8723BE PCIe, which is not currently working. I suspect I managed to ruin the drivers, when trying to get bluetooth to work. This is the operating system and kernel:

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Kernel: Linux 3.19.0-65-generic
Architecture: x86_64
```

The system does recognize the wireless network card.
`sudo lshw -C network` returns:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b2500000-b2503fff
```

And `iwconfig` returns:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`rfkill list` does not return anything.

I tried following the instructions here:
[Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Which did not help me.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/800910/ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-wireless-not-working-after-updates

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks @Pilot6 :)