# Wifi going to "sleep" after several minutes of internet inactivity (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04

As the title says.

I can be surfing the web just fine, but for example after stopping at a link to read a lengthy article or watch a video, upon continuing my browsing I have to wait an extended amount of time for the connection to re-establish, usually about 30s to 1m. After that I can resume internet use as usual until the next period of inactivity. Also during the inactive period, the bit-rate drops from a usual 72Mb/s to 7 Mb/s.

**At the moment I am using an** `rtl8192cu` **chipset** with the default Ubuntu 16.04 drivers. I have found a possible solution offered here: [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04) but I am hesitant in installing the package just yet knowing how easy it is to bork your system with a faulty update. I'd rather not risk losing total internet connection as wireless is my main mode of access.

```
lsmod | grep rtl output:
rtl8xxxu               69632  0
rtl8192cu              65536  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        49152  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                69632  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
mac80211              659456  4 rtl8xxxu,rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              499712  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
```

Already tried:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8192cu_pci"
```

---

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
```

Although it looks like iwlwifi is disabled by default in lsmod

Again I am not quite trusting in the update although it seems like people have reported success after following the steps. Has anyone installed the package here recently and can back up the claims of it working?