# Can't install Ubuntu on HP Probook 455 G3

Tags: boot, 16.04, uefi, hp

Trying to boot a HP ProBook 455 G3 (Windows 10) from a USB with Ubuntu. 12.04 succeeds, but no wifi. 14.04 and 16.04 don't do so well. Just a dark screen. With 16.04 Mate, the logo appears briefly before the dark screen. ctrl alt F2 followed by ctrl alt del causes a restart, so something is running in that inky blackness. I thought this would be a piece of cake as I had read that this model can be shipped with Ubuntu pre-installed if bought from Amazon. I have got fast start in Windoes turned off. Fast boot is turned off. I've tried different permutations of uefi v legacy and safe mode. Couldn't find a toggle for CSM.
I thought that I would ask the universe before taking the long winded route of installing 12.04, fixing the wifi issue and then upgrading to (eventually) 16.04?

Comment: There are numerous "black screen" problem reports on this site; you can [search to find them.](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=%22black+screen%22+site%3Aaskubuntu.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) Solutions vary depending on the video chipset in use and other factors.

Comment: I have managed to boot Ubuntu Mate 16.04 live CD with nomodeset parameter. No wifi and iffy graphics support. I suppose I need to find drivers for these things ans see how they get on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of black screen is with AMD Carrizo card and amdgpu opensource driver. The 14.04 work and you can install private drivers from catalyst, but the wi-fi drivers not work, exist a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04).

Answer (score 0):

If the wireless adapter works in Ubuntu 12.04 it will likely work in future releases too albeit with some tweaks. You'd probably have to perform the same tweaks if you upgraded from 12.04 to a later release. Please open a new question with concrete information about your computer's wireless adapter (the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network` should be enough) and your experience with it.

As for the black screen when you try to install Ubuntu, please refer to “[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](/q/162075/175814)” If that's not enough please open *another* more concrete question with more information about your computer's graphics adapter (e. g. `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA`) and your specific experience in the light of the linked question.