# HP Pavillion won't connect to wifi : rtl8723be

Tags: wireless, 16.04, hp, realtek-wireless, rtl8723be

I have an HP Pavillion laptop and recently I've shifted to Ubuntu 16.04 from Windows 10. I have a realtek rtl8723be wifi card. I can see the Wifi networks but cannot connect to them. On trying to connect ubuntu constantly prompts me to enter the wifi password. I did some research and followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04) answer to fix this but the problem persists.

What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all remove the settings you made.

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

If you do not have this file, nothing is wrong.

Then install a good driver

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

Reboot and enjoy

If you still have problems, you may need to add an option:

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

then reboot again.

If you do not have any internet connection, you can download the package using another computer, a phone, etc.

The package is [HERE](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.10_all.deb)

You will also need DKMS installed. You can find the DKMS package for Ubuntu 16.04 [`HERE`](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb)

Copy these two files to the Ubuntu Home folder (~/) and run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb rtlwifi*.deb
```

Then reboot.