# HP260 G2 RTL8723BE wireless error

Tags: realtek-wireless, rtl8723be, pcie

Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS. Nettop HP260G2 with Intel 4405U CPU and DDR4 memory. Sometimes Wi-Fi comes unstable and turns off until reboot.

Installing `rtlwifi_new` by these instructions [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04) changes nothing.

Boot log contains a list of messages like these:

```
[   45.297286] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3:    [ 0] Receiver Error        
[   45.297292] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e3
[   45.297658] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: can't find device of ID00e3
[   45.297661] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e3
[   45.297668] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e3(Receiver ID)
[   45.297671] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3:   device [8086:9d13] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[   45.297673] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3:    [ 0] Receiver Error        
[   45.297678] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e3
[   45.298027] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: can't find device of ID00e3
[   45.302343] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e3
[   45.302355] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e3(Receiver ID)
[   45.302359] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3:   device [8086:9d13] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[   45.302362] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3:    [ 0] Receiver Error        
[   45.302368] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e3
[   45.302718] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: can't find device of ID00e3
[   45.302972] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e3
[   45.302981] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e3(Receiver ID)
[   45.302984] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3:   device [8086:9d13] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[   45.302987] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3:    [ 0] Receiver Error        
[   45.302993] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e3
[   45.303341] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: can't find device of ID00e3
[   45.307352] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e3
```

Tried to install **rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.10_all.deb** driver following instructions from here: [How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-8723be-wireless-card-to-work)

Wifi is now working with new driver - Bluetooth symbol is hide. But boot still logging the same errors.

What's wrong here? Thanks everybody for help.

Comment: Device 8086:9d13 is a PCI bridge. I assume this is the PCI slot to which the wireless is attached. It appears to be a hardware issue. After undertaking all safety procedures outlined in the service manual that you can probably access on line, I suggest that you unplug and then firmly replug the wireless card. Reboot and check the logs again.

Comment: Thanks for comment! Nettop is brand new and I can not disassemble it with no warranty loss. When working - WiFi has normal speed and stability of connection. Troubles onlu seen in log or after some time of work.