# Cannot install drivers for my Realtek rtl8723be wifi card in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, apt, package-management, realtek

**Tried**

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

**But giving**

```
whiplash@whiplash-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms    
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree           
Reading state information... Done    
E: Unable to locate package rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

**My wireless card details:**

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: a8:a7:95:23:cb:25
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.8.0-27-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a1103fff
```

Comment: As i see [here](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+packages) the package `rtlwifi-new-dkms` isn't available for Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety). The latest Ubuntu version that is supported by this PPA repository is 16.04 (Xenial). I think you should download the package for Ubuntu 16.04 and force `dpkg` to install it. Be careful about this solution. Maybe it causes broken `dpkg` database!

Comment: You already have drivers for your wifi, is there a problem?

Comment: As @Jeremy31 says, you already have a driver. Installing an *older* version not written specifically for your kernel version is unlikely to help. Please tell us what problem you are having.

Comment: The problem is I should sit very close to the router, or else due to weak signal strength I can't connect to the wifi. The issue is with the weak signal strength

Comment: You don't need that package as the ant_sel parameter is already in the kernel module and it is usually needed with an HP laptop

Comment: You can build the drivers manually by following instructions mentioned in answer to this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04 I have successfully tried them in Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maintain the `hanipouspilot` PPA. That is why I can give the best answer ;-)

I did not upload an `rtlwifi-new-dkms` package for Yakkety 16.10.

You can try to download the deb for Xenial, but it is unlikely that it will build for the 4.8 kernel. I did not test it.

The reason is simple. I do not use this release and I can't test the module.

You can try to use a driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

Comment: Are you going to upload soon for Yakkety 16.10?

Comment: Or should I roll back to 16.04 LTS?

Comment: I did not plan to support yakkety in my PPA. Probably I will do it some time, but no promise.