# modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Exec format error [wifi]

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

I have restarted my computer after an update, then I have noticed that the wifi signal was very weak. I have decided to download this package `https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new` and reinstall the wifi driver but I have the following error: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Exec format error`

I run the following in the package downloaded:

```
make
sudo make install
modinfo -p rtl8723be
```

I have following result :

```
swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0)
 (int)
```

.

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be

sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

I have following result :

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Exec format error
```

I have tried to restart the adapter with the following command:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

I'm using **ubuntu 17.04 | 4.10.0-33-generic**

Comment: You don't need to install anything for 17.04. Uninstall the custom module.

Comment: @Pilot6 , If I run the following command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall rtlwifi_new-master linux-firmware`
 in the folder of the downloaded package , I have this error : E: Unable to locate package rtlwifi_new-master

Comment: This command could not output anything else. There is no `rtlwifi_new-master` package. You need to uninstall what you installed from git. You need to run `sudo make uninstall` from the directory with the source.

Comment: @Pilot6,  I just uninstall the package , but my wifi adapter still not detected .

Comment: @Pilot6, I fix my issue by following the step in this answer: [rlt8723be](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04). Thank so much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, i used to run make, install, mod....etc commands from the same old directory "rtlwifi_new"(which i downloaded a month ago) .

Try a fresh installation by downloading all files again.

Answer (score 1):

if you have rtlwifi_new downloaded,

```
cd rtlwifi_new
sudo make uninstall
sudo make clean
```

Then, make, install and insert the module. Don't re-download the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Same as  @Pilot6 (thanks!!!), I fixed my issue with: [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04)

After every kernel update:

1. Execute

   ```
    cd rtlwifi_new
   ```
2. Clean previous builds with

   ```
    make clean
   ```
3. Update git repository with

   ```
    git pull
   ```
4. Compile it with

   ```
    make clean && make
   ```
5. And install with

   ```
    sudo make install
   ```
6. Reboot or unload/load modules.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the modprobe.d folder in root>>etc using terminal and remove the rtl8723de.conf if it exists.Use

```
sudo rm rtl8723de.conf
```

It worked for me, try a fresh installation of the wifi driver. You can clone the repository again and start again if you face problem in installation.