# Wifi-Adapter not found, then fixed, now lost again, same solution does not work: Exec format error

Tags: command-line, drivers, wireless

I am using my new HP laptop with a clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04, named Bionic Beaver.  Because the wifi-adapter wasn't detected, I followed the steps in this article: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/no-wifi-adapter-found-hp-laptops-ubuntu-18-04/

And after that it worked fine.  Here are those steps:

`git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git`

`cd rtlwifi_new/ && git checkout origin/extended -b extended`

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git`

`sudo make install`

`sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de`

`sudo modprobe rtl8723de`

It worked!  It was weak, but with the following command it got stronger:

`sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2`

I was happy, and later I shut down the computer.  Today, I started it up, and the wifi-adapter again was not detected.  I still had the git repository, and the extended branch, so I ran the commands again, thinking I would have to make a script to run every time on start up.

but running the `sudo modprobe rtl8723de` command yields the following error:

`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723de': Exec format error`

Based on a comment in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950883/modprobe-error-could-not-insert-rtl8723be-exec-format-error-wifi), which was not conclusively answered, I tried 'sudo make uninstall'
[image: comment from Pilot6]

But it did not detect the wifi, and when I reinstalled, it was the same.

Why did my fix not 'stick'?  And how can I 'reset' or get it to work again?

---

As directed in a comment, here are the results of running `make`:

`make -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-16-generic/build M=/home/alex/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-16-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 19 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-16-generic'`

Separating these commands has no effect on the output from `sudo modprobe rtl8723de`

---

Again as directed:

Results of : `dpkg -l * 4.18 * | grep ii`

`ii  linux-headers-4.18.0-15                4.18.0-15.16~18.04.1 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.18.0
ii  linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic        4.18.0-15.16~18.04.1 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.18.0-16                4.18.0-16.17~18.04.1 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.18.0
ii  linux-headers-4.18.0-16-generic        4.18.0-16.17~18.04.1 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic          4.18.0-15.16~18.04.1 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.18.0-16-generic          4.18.0-16.17~18.04.1 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-modules-4.18.0-15-generic        4.18.0-15.16~18.04.1 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-4.18.0-16-generic        4.18.0-16.17~18.04.1 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-15-generic  4.18.0-15.16~18.04.1 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-16-generic  4.18.0-16.17~18.04.1 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP`

results of : `modinfo rtl8723de | grep ver`

`filename:       /lib/modules/4.18.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723de/rtl8723de.ko
srcversion:     37BE84E7F4EC43A12099BF7
vermagic:       4.18.0-15-generic SMP mod_unload`

---

This is a Make log file for DKMS:

`DKMS make.log for rtlwifi_new-0.6 for kernel 4.18.0-16-generic (x86_64)
vie mar 15 19:36:12 -05 2019
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-16-generic'
scripts/Makefile.build:45: /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:1534: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build' failed
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-16-generic'`

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status`. Also, break your `sudo make install` into two commands... `make` and `sudo make install`. Show me any text/errors after the `make` command.

Comment: @heynnema after installing dkms and running `dkms status`, there is no output.  I will update the question with results of the make command.

Comment: This may take a little time... so please be patient. Show me `dpkg -l *4.18* | grep ii` and `modinfo rtl8723de | grep ver`. Then, after editing your question with that output, try `make clean` then `make` then `sudo make install` and report back.

Comment: @heynnema  `make clean`, `make` and then `make install` resulted in success.  I again needed to use the command `sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2` in order for it to work at any distance.  I am unsure how to continue with the question, on the one hand, my problem is solved, on the other I do want to know why this reset when I shut down, and how to 'make it stick'.  Thank you for *your* patience with me!

Comment: Why not use dkms?  `sudo dkms add ~/rtlwifi_new && sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6`

Comment: @Alex yes, the next step is dkms. This will mean that you won't have to redo this every time you get a kernel update. I'll put together an answer that you can follow, and then accept, ok?

Comment: @Jeremy31 dkms was exactly my next step... but I was waiting for it to work using the old school compile/install first.

Comment: @Alex just for learning purposes... the problem that you had before was (as seen via the `modinfo rtl8723de | grep ver` command) that the filename and vermagic numbers don't match for the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the current problem, we'll do this...

```
make clean                        # clean up leftovers
make                              # compile the software
sudo make install                 # install the software
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de        # unload the driver
sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2 # reload the driver with options
```

**That was successful**. However, doing it this way will require that you redo this every time the kernel gets updated via `Software Updates`. Boo.

---

Lets redo some of our steps, and use **dkms**, and make it so that it rebuilds itself when the kernel gets updated.

First, set the `terminal` back into the prior directory, and uninstall the current working driver...

```
cd ~/rtl8723de         # change directory
sudo modinfo rtl8723de # see the installed driver
sudo make uninstall    # uninstall the driver
sudo modinfo rtl8723de # make sure it's gone
cd                     # change to ~ directory
```

Now we install using **dkms**... using the unzipped folder, or the `git clone` folder...

If any of the following steps fail, then **stop** and report back.

```
sudo apt install dkms build-essential     # already done
cd ~/rtlwifi_new                          # enter the directory
sudo make clean                           # clean up from prior "make"
cd                                        # go to ~ directory
sudo cp -a ~/rtlwifi_new /usr/src/rtlwifi-new-0.6    # copy to /usr/src
sudo dkms add rtlwifi-new/0.6             # add the software to dkms
sudo dkms build rtlwifi-new/0.6           # build the software
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6         # install the software
dkms status                               # review the status
```

---

**Update #1:**

Due to some naming problems, we have to clean things up a little before continuing. Do these commands first, then go back and do my original (modified) **dkms** installation instructions, shown immediately above. Pay special attention to hyphens vs underscores.

If any of the following steps fail, then **stop** and report back.

```
dkms status # note the name of the rtlwifi driver... probably rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms remove rtlwifi_new/0.6 --all # remove from dkms
sudo rm -r /usr/src/rtlwifi_new-0.6 # delete directory
ls -al /var/lib/dkms # make sure there are no rtlwifi directories left
```

---

**Update #2:**

Once we get the **dkms** driver properly installed, we need to create a configuration file to select the correct wireless antenna.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
```

enter the following line...

```
options rtl8723de ant_sel=2
```

save file and quit gedit

reboot and check wireless operation

**Update #3:**

**Success!**

Comment: Ok, I am reporting back.  While copying rtlwifi_new-master, it informs me that no such file or directory exists.  Looking around, the repository is rtlwifi_new and inside there are (among other things) directories for the drivers (rtl8723de, among others) and some files called rtlwifi (.ko, .mod.c, .mod.o, and .o).  It doesn't seem like you wanted me to copy a directory, or you would have included an -r flag, right?  I will try copying some things.  As always, *thank you*.

Comment: @Alex yes, depending on how you got the software, via `git clone`, or download the .zip file, it looks like the folder names are different. So change the `cp` command and lose the `-master` part, and it should work fine. Don't try and proceed with these commands if mine fail... talk to me first.

Comment: @Alex see slight edit to dkms instructions

Comment: ok!  The copy worked fine without the -master tail,  the `dkms add` worked and created the symlink to that folder.  With the `dkms build` command, I got the error: `Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.18.0-16-generic (x86_64)`  It gives me the log to consult, I will look and copy over to here.

Comment: @Alex I had slightly changed the instruction whilst you were probably doing them... so for now... in `terminal`, `cd /usr/src/rtlwifi_new-0.6`, `sudo make clean`, then `cd`, then retry the `dkms build` command. Show me the log if it fails. Report back.

Comment: I got the same error, above is the log file output.  The UI here on stack exchange is telling me that I am making too many comments!  But I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: @Alex it's **really** difficult to read the log when placed into comments. Can you please delete that comment, and then copy/paste the log as an edit to your question, and use the {} icon to format the text if required. We're going to have to debug someone else's code... argh... let me know when you're done with the log edit... did you do the `sudo make clean` in the /usr/src/rtl... directory?

Comment: Done!   Yes, I did do the sudo make clean, and in the right directory.  If it helps, I think you must be a super hero.

Comment: @Alex ok... I think I see what's wrong... grrr. It'll take a little while for me to write an update to my instructions... and it's dinner time here... tell me... where is your git folder... on your ~/Desktop, or elsewhere?  Show me `ls -al /var/lib/dkms` and `ls -al /usr/src` and `dkms status`. Also edit that output into your question, not the comments, and then let me know it's there. I'll get back to this after dinner, ok?

Comment: please, enjoy your family.  I too have pushed this beyond office hours.  I appreciate your help, tomorrow I will edit my answer and we can start fresh at your convenience then, on Monday or whenever :)  

The git folder is in my home (~).

Comment: @Alex OK, dinner is down the hatch... I've added Update #1 to my answer. Do it first, then backtrack and redo my (modified) dkms installation instructions. If this conversation gets moved to chat by the moderators, make sure to start comments to me with "@heynnema" (no quotes) or I'll certainly miss them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91132/discussion-between-alex-and-heynnema).