# WiFi (rtl8723be) unable to resolve DNS (17.04)

Tags: networking, 17.04, dns

Laptop: HP ay513tx, 
Wireless Card: Realtek 8723be, 
OS: Xubuntu 17.04, 
WiFi interface: wlo1

Problem: WiFi doesn't resolve DNS from time to time. I have checked and searched through a lot of topics in Askubuntu and Stackoverflow in general, tried installing updated drivers from custom PPA (according to an answer), tried [setting various options to the driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04).

I also had to set the ant_sel=2 to get my WiFi strength high.

What happens is, when OS boots up or re-boots, it works fine. But after sometime, let's say 10 minutes, I see that web pages are timing out. So I check the ping, where it shows that it can ping to 8.8.8.8 properly, but can't ping "google.com", indicating that it's unable to resolve the host, whereas actual network connection is working fine (as it can ping to external IP).

(It works perfectly fine in Windows 10 on the same laptop though, so it has something to do with Ubuntu)

At this point of time what I have to do is reboot the OS, or disable and enable the WiFi. If someone can point me to a solution, it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Checking Default route
Use one of these commands:

```
route -n
```

or

```
ip r
```

Ask a new IP address and amend the connection with the next command:

```
dhclient -v wlan0
```

Now, all should work fine!