# Problems with wifi range on laptop. Wifi card: realtek rtl8723be

Tags: wireless, realtek

So I just started using linux/ubuntu today and I've been getting problems with my wifi, ive tried the solutions on this page: [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04)
When im really close to my router, its fine, i can see wifi signals, but when i go just a few steps back it disappears right away. Im using the latest version of ubuntu 17.10

Any suggestions would be nice! :)

Comment: You also need ant_sel=1 or else =2 from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work/635629#635629

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|level'
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2
iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|level'
```

Once you find what setting is best, then

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=X" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be-ant.conf
```

Replace X with whatever setting worked better