# RTL8723BE Wifi not working after waking up from suspend Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wireless, 17.10, rtl8723be

I got my wifi working using the solution from : [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04)

But the issue is, it stops working after waking up from suspend. I have to restart the laptop to get it working again. I tried searching here a lot but couldn't find the answer. Can anyone help me?