# Wifi dropping and slow - Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

It takes about 30 seconds to load any website, and randomly drops off wifi, I have ran the wireles info script... how can I fix it?

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 09 Jun 2019 18:42 CEST +0200

Booted last: 09 Jun 2019 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.18.0-21-generic #22~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 16 15:07:19 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:5110]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:b736]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2c70 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

'mokutil' is not installed (package "mokutil").

##### lsmod #############################

wmi_bmof               16384  0
rtl8723be              98304  0
btcoexist             155648  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                32768  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                90112  4 rtl_pci,rtl8723be,btcoexist,rtl8723_common
mac80211              802816  3 rtl_pci,rtl8723be,rtlwifi
cfg80211              667648  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
wmi                    24576  1 wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 10.253.202.81/18 brd 10.253.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 13346sec preferred_lft 13346sec
    inet6 2001:6b0:17:fc09:3895:b8ec:e206:34a1/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 603748sec preferred_lft 84755sec
    inet6 2001:6b0:17:fc09:eda2:154f:d43e:9f91/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2590948sec preferred_lft 603748sec
    inet6 fe80::cac1:8c24:23b5:3d5c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"eduroam"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'eduroam' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=4 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:11   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via 10.253.192.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.253.192.0/18 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.253.202.81 metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search clients.eduroam.liu.se liu.se

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       511     1  0 18:24 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8723be
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.18.0-21-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.3/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp3s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     eduroam
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       df15e9f1-849e-45a4-bb28-b9680ff31155
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     72 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.253.202.81/18
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.253.192.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.253.192.0/18, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 10.253.192.1, mt = 600
IP4.DNS[1]:                             130.236.1.9
IP4.DNS[2]:                             130.236.1.10
IP4.DNS[3]:                             130.236.1.11
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          clients.eduroam.liu.se
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.192.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 130.236.1.9 130.236.1.10 130.236.1.11
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 10.253.202.81
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 130.236.0.254
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 10.253.255.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       domain_search = clients.eduroam.liu.se. liu.se.
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 10.253.192.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       domain_name = clients.eduroam.liu.se
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1560111905
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       host_name = alan
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 10.253.192.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       ntp_servers = 130.236.7.54 130.236.141.6
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 14400
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2001:6b0:17:fc09:3895:b8ec:e206:34a1/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2001:6b0:17:fc09:eda2:154f:d43e:9f91/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::cac1:8c24:23b5:3d5c/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::209:fff:fe09:22
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = 2001:6b0:17:fc09::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.ROUTE[5]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::209:fff:fe09:22, mt = 600
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2001:6b0:17:f000::9
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = 2001:6b0:17:f000::9
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:1:0:1:1c:a3:f0:14:0:25:90:e8:5a:ba
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:c3:4f:0:f7:5b:24:33:a7:23:a8:9b:72:99:f:82:6e
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1,3}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   df15e9f1-849e-45a4-bb28-b9680ff31155 | eduroam
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   7e5aab4a-e3f8-40fb-99e8-6125a2df4f8d | LiU

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID                        BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY     ACTIVE  IN-USE 
LIUAT2                      <MAC 'LIUAT2' [AC8]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  195 Mbit/s  64      ▂▄▆_  WPA2         no             
LIUAT2                      <MAC 'LIUAT2' [AC5]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  195 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA2         no             
LiU                         <MAC 'LiU' [AC2]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  195 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  --           no             
LiU                         <MAC 'LiU' [AC3]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  195 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  --           no             
eduroam                     <MAC 'eduroam' [AN5]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  195 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2 802.1X  no             
eduroam                     <MAC 'eduroam' [AC4]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  195 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA2 802.1X  no             
LIUAT2                      <MAC 'LIUAT2' [AC6]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  195 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA2         no             
HORS                        <MAC 'HORS' [AC10]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  130 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA2         no             
LiU                         <MAC 'LiU' [AN9]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  195 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  --           no             
DIRECT-ae-HP M452 LaserJet  <MAC 'DIRECT-ae-HP M452 LaserJet' [AN10]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  65 Mbit/s   54      ▂▄__  WPA2         no             
K3                          <MAC 'K3' [AC11]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  130 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2         no             
eduroam                     <MAC 'eduroam' [AC1]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  195 Mbit/s  53      ▂▄__  WPA2 802.1X  yes     *      
LiU                         <MAC 'LiU' [AN13]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  195 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  --           no             
LIUAT2                      <MAC 'LIUAT2' [AN14]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  195 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA2         no             
eduroam                     <MAC 'eduroam' [AN15]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  195 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA2 802.1X  no             
eduroam                     <MAC 'eduroam' [AN16]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  195 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA2 802.1X  no             

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/_Linkoping WiFi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=_Linkoping WiFi | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=_Linkoping WiFi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/LiU]] (600 root)
[connection] id=LiU | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=LiU
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eduroam]] (600 root)
[connection] id=eduroam | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=eduroam
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Stockholm (based on set time zone)

global
country SE: DFS-ETSI
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

wlp3s0    13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      7   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlp3s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'eduroam' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"eduroam"
                    Bit Rates:12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                              54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000081c86833822
                    Extra: Last beacon: 256ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'LiU' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"LiU"
                    Bit Rates:12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                              54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000081c8684d022
                    Extra: Last beacon: 204ms ago
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'LiU' [AC3]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"LiU"
                    Bit Rates:12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                              54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000808ac1b2822
                    Extra: Last beacon: 204ms ago
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'eduroam' [AC4]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"eduroam"
                    Bit Rates:12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                              54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000808ac199022
                    Extra: Last beacon: 252ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'LIUAT2' [AC5]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"LIUAT2"
                    Bit Rates:12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                              54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000081c8684d022
                    Extra: Last beacon: 228ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'LIUAT2' [AC6]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"LIUAT2"
                    Bit Rates:12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                              54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000808ac1b2822
                    Extra: Last beacon: 228ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 07 - Address: <MAC 'net1-2135DA' [AC7]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"net1-2135DA"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000004479fb0166
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2544ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 08 - Address: <MAC 'LIUAT2' [AC8]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"LIUAT2"
                    Bit Rates:12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                              54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000004bc7171d565
                    Extra: Last beacon: 64ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 09 - Address: <MAC 'LiU' [AC9]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"LiU"
                    Bit Rates:12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
```

Comment: Try `echo "options rtl8723be ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` and `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` then reboot, if that doesn't help do `./wireless-info && cat wireless-info.txt` post URL

Comment: I have executed both    echo "options rtl8723be ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf    and    sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*    then rebooted and it is still slow... I also executed the last part but, that I think is just what I did before and posted in the question... what URL should I post?

Comment: Forgot part `cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999`  That should show a URL in terminal as a result to post

Comment: https://termbin.com/u7c0

Comment: I am not sure I can help because this is the problem "Limiting TX power to 4 dBm as advertised by <MAC 'eduroam'"

Comment: sorry but, what that means? Is that a parameter from 'eduroam'? I connected to the same wifi using my phone and Windows and it works fine, is just with my Ubuntu the issue. Shall I try connecting to another network and executing `cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999` ?

Comment: Have you read this Q&A yet?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I wouldn't bother with rtlwifi_new, eduroam is forcing a very low tx power from your wifi card

Comment: I will then try to stay closer to the access point, is if that helps, thanks!