# Weak and disconnecting wifi with RTL8821CE that is strong with windows

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, 20.04, windows, rtl

I have a 2 antenna wifi that gets a great signal on windows.  On dual boot Ubuntu 20.04, it's very weak, to the point that it starts disconnecting if kept on long enough. Any ideas of what could cause this? I tried setting wifi.powrsave = 2, turning off IPV6, and turning off fast startup on windows and reinstalling Ubuntu.

Edit: I've also tried setting antenna to 1 or 2, that didn't help, and I wouldn't expect it to since I have 2 antennas

Comment: Did you try any ant_sel=1  (or 2) options? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04 or google ant_sel

Comment: @ubfan from what I understand, that's if one only has one antenna, I have 2, so selecting one doesn't do anything, though I did try

Comment: Take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide  Just to be clear, you tried both ant_sel=2 and =1 and the signal strengths were the same in both cases?  What hardware do you have, and what driver are you using.

Comment: Yes I tried ant_sel = 1 and 2, I have 2 antennas, it didn't help the signal strength. I'm using dkms source for the realtek 8821C PCIe wifi driver from rtl8821ce-dkms (open source). The antennas came with the adapter I think

Comment: @ubfan I think the first post involves problems with the rtl8723be specifically, or for people with 1 antenna but two possible antenna connections

Comment: @ubfan maybe I am lacking something installed, but nm-tool does not work for me, that the trouble shooting starts with

Comment: I guess one uses nmcli instead of nm-tool now, kinda odd the documentation wouldn't be updated though