# How to pass kernel parameters from pxe server?

Tags: kernel, nfs, pxe

I have a set of computers loading Ubuntu from a PXE server.
I'm changing base image and in the new one I need to pass a kernel parameter to the OS (this one: amdgpu.vm_fragment_size=9).

During testing I put it in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT variable in /etc/default/grub and run update-grub, like you do, but now I'm booting from the PXE server, so I can't do that.

This is my pxelinux.cfg file:

```
DEFAULT ubuntu
LABEL ubuntu
KERNEL /vmlinux-4.8.17-040817-generic
APPEND ip=dhcp rw root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.254:/diskless/ubuntu/0185 raid=noautodetect quiet splash
INITRD /initrd.img-4.8.17-040817-generic
```

I tried to add the variable at the end of the APPEND line, it looks like this now:

```
DEFAULT ubuntu
LABEL ubuntu
KERNEL /vmlinux-4.8.17-040817-generic
APPEND ip=dhcp rw root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.254:/diskless/ubuntu/0185 raid=noautodetect quiet splash amdgpu.vm_fragment_size=9
INITRD /initrd.img-4.8.17-040817-generic
```

And I used `/etc/init.d/nfs restart` to apply the changes, but it didn't work.
I also tried the method described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/496842) answer, it didn't work.

I should also say that this is my first time using a PXE server and/or NSF, so I might be missing something basic, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first method I showed is actually correct, I just forgot to load the right kernel. Everything is working fine now.

Comment: Awesome. With this method, I could make the installer fill in the `host` and `domain` parameters! Otherwise, the installer stops to ask these params because the the actual preseed file loads after this step.